# If $(X_n)$ is independent with $X_n$ Bernoulli of parameter $\frac1n$, how to show that $X_n$ doesn't converge almost surely to $0$?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

If $X_n \sim Bernoulli(\frac{1}{n})$ independently, then I know that because $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X_n = 1) = \infty$. Then by Borel-Cantelli, I know that $P(\limsup_{n \to \infty}\{X_n=1\}) = 1$. This means that the event $\{X_n = 1\}$ happens infinitely often with probability 1. However, I do not know how to rigorously use this to prove that $X_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ almost surely. I know that the definition of almost sure convergence is:

$$
P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n(\omega) = X\}) = 1
$$

How can I use the above to show that this doesn't hold?

Comment: You have a sequence of 0 and 1 with infinitely many 1 and you are asking why this sequence does not converge to 0, right? Is the solution clearer using this reformulation?

Comment: You are done: You showed that sequence $X_n$ doesn't converge to 0 almost everywhere, since the set on which it doesn't converge to $0$ has probability $1$.

Comment: I am wondering how this can be proved explicitly using the definition of almost sure convergence.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3725336/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\mathbb P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\right\} \right)=1 
$$
is equivalent to 
$$\mathbb P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\liminf_{n\to\infty} |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|<\varepsilon \right\}\right)=1, \text{ for all }\varepsilon > 0. 
 $$
This follows directly from the definition of convergence of a sequence of real numbers:
$$\omega\in\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n= X\right\}\implies \omega\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon \}, \text{ for all }\varepsilon > 0.$$
Now, since
\begin{align}
\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\ \{X_n=1\}\right)^c &= \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=1\} \right)^c\\
&= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=0\}\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty}\ \{X_n=0\},
\end{align}
we see that 
$$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\ \{X_n=0\}\right)=0. $$
From this the result follows immediately.

Comment: @Did When you edit my posts, would you mind noting the changes in the edit summary?

Comment: Why  not. $ $ $ $

Comment: Can you elaborate why the third line equation holds? I understand that if the limit exists, then an element in the limit is in the limit infimum, but I thought that this wasn't true the opposite way around, that if an element is in the limit infimum it doesn't have to be in the limit?

Comment: @Math1000 Doesn't the third line not hold for the opposite direction? Meaning it is not an if and only if statement but rather only for one-direction?

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $A$ the event $\{\limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n=1\}$ (shorthand notation for $\{\omega : \limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n(\omega)=1\}$). You have already proved that $P(A)=1$.

Let us call $B$ the event $\{\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n=0\}$  (shorthand notation for $\{\omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n(\omega)=0\}$). Almost sure convergence is equivalent (according to your definition) to $P(B)=1$

But the events $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (this is not probability anymore, just the mere deterministic fact that a sequence that has infinitely many ones can't converge to zero).

So $B \subset A^C$ so $P(B) \leq P(A^C) = 1-P(A) = 1-1 = 0$. Hence $P(B)=0$ so the definition of almost sure convergence is not met.

---

That was the developed argument, once you get more accustomed to probability you'd say : Almost surely the sequence has infinetely many ones, so almost surely it does not converge to 0, so there can't be almost sure convergence.

---

Last remark, you haven't just proven **no almost sure convergence**, but the stronger statement of **almost-sure non convergence**. Try to wrap your head around these two statements, and to write their formal definition yourself as a good exercise.