# Showing $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ almost surely does not converge to $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $ X_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$  almost surely does not converge to $0$; $X_n$'s are independent.

Therefore I got the hint to use Borel-Cantelli and showed that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X_n=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$ and so
$P(\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}X_n)=1$.

Can I now follow that it is not possible that $X_n$ converges almost sure to $0$ because the probability that infinity $X_n=1$ happens is $1$ ?
Maybe you can help me with that

Comment: What do you mean by $P(\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}X_n)=1$? I think there is something missing in the brackets. Hint: If you know that limsup is a.s. not $0$ and you suppose convergence, then lim=limsup=liminf, so especially lim is not equal to $0$.

Comment: If I want to show that $X_n$ is a.s convergent to $0$ I have to show that $P( \lim_n{ \to \infty}X_n=0)=1$ or not? With Borel-Cantelli I was abled to show that $P(\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}X_n=1)=1$ or not? But how can this help me with the question $P( \lim_n{ \to \infty}X_n=0)=1$ can i say because $P(\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}X_n=1)=1$ is true $P( \lim_n{ \to \infty}X_n=0)=1$ can't be true?

Comment: I think I got it

Answer (score 4):

**If** $X_n$ are independent, the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) says $\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n =1\right) = 1$, i.e. that with probability $1$, infinitely many $X_n = 1$. But if $X_n \to 0$, there would have to be some $N$ such that $|X_n| < 1/2$ for all $n > N$.  Since $X_n$ can only take values $0$ and $1$, that means $X_n = 0$ for all $n > N$.
But that would say only finitely many $X_n = 1$.
So with probability $1$, that doesn't happen.

Comment: but if $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n^2}$, then $X_n \to X$ a.s., i.e. only finitely many $X_n=1$. Idon't see how this could follow from the statement 'there would have to be some $N$ such that $|X_n|<\frac{1}{2} \forall n >N$'

Comment: If $P(X_n = 1) = 1/n^2$, since $\sum_n 1/n^2 < \infty$ the first Borel-Cantelli lemma says $\mathbb P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = 1) = 0$.  If $|X_n| < 1/2$ for all $n > N$, that says $X_n = 0$ for all $n > N$, so there are only finitely many $X_n = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a Bernoulli, not Binomial. First, show convergence in probability (by Markoff inequality):
$$
P(|X_n-0|>\varepsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbf{E} X_n}{\varepsilon} = \frac{1}{n \varepsilon} \to 0
$$
so $X_n \to_p 0$. Now, for convergence a.s. you need $P(\limsup X_n \neq 0) = 0 \Leftrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(|X_k -0|> \varepsilon) < \infty$:
$$
P(\limsup X_n \neq 0) \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(|X_k-0|> \varepsilon) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X_k> \varepsilon) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \to \infty
$$
Since the measure on the $\limsup$ on this set is 1, $X_n \not\to X$ a.s.

Comment: I'm quite sure that $\operatorname{Bin}\left(1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is the binomial distribution and  $1$ being the total number of experiments and $\frac{1}{n}$ the probability of each experiment

Comment: Then you have $\binom{1}{k} (\frac{1}{n})^k(1-\frac{1}{n})^{1-k}$. Plug in $k=0,1$ and you get $Bernoulli(\frac{1}{n})$